# Vectorize scipy.integrate.quad

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using `scipy.integrate.quad(f, a, b, args=(c,))` to integrate function `f` between `a` and `b`, adding another parameter `c`. You can think about `f` as

```
f = lambda x, y: x*y
```

As I understand it, the function requires `a`, `b`, `c` to be float values. However, I have many integrals to solve, all with the same function, just over vectors of `a`, `b`, and `c`. Iterating through all the vectors is quite inefficient. Is there any way to speed up / vectorize this operation?

Comment: Different `a` and `b` means evaluating `f` over different ranges, and different number of intervals.  That makes vectorization (think 2d grid) next to impossible.

Comment: @hpaulj under certain smoothness conditions, at least having `c` as a vector should be "easily" doable.

Comment: `quad` calls FORTRAN code, so for what it does it is probably as efficient as can be.  So either you call it fewer times in a smarter way.  Or you write your own integetrator (or find another) that exploits parallelism (most likely linearity) in your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Alas, this is not supported by `integrate.quad`.

You *might* find better luck with using gaussian quadratures yourself: `scipy.integra.fixed_quad` chokes on array_like input, but the lower-level routines which compute roots and weights *should* work. See "Roots and weights for orthogonal polynomials" section [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/special.html).
YMMV though.

Answer (score 3):

It looks that meanwhile numpy has responded to this by implementing [numpy.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)
with an example covered in [integrate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html). Here is modified example with two variables:

```
fun2int = lambda x, a: np.sqrt(x+a)
intfun = lambda a: integrate.quad(fun2int, 0, 4, args=(a))[0]
vec_int = np.vectorize(intfun)
vec_int(np.linspace(0,2,5))
Out[1]: array([5.33333333, 6.12825877, 6.78689326, 7.37435069, 7.91234089])
```

There is also integrate.quad_vec (scipy.**version** of 1.4.1), but I did not test that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well the problem, I would just run the function over an array of `a,b,c` parameters. For instance, set an array of two sets of `a,b,c` as:

```
a = np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3], [0.9,0.8,0.3]])
```

then set an empty list to store results:

```
L = []
```

and loop through the array:

```
for a,b,c in a:

    b = integrate.quad(f, a, b, args=(c,))
    L.append(b)
```

The result is a list of tuples:

```
[(0.004500000000000001, 4.996003610813206e-17), (-0.025499999999999995, 2.8310687127941485e-16)]
```

Maybe there is a more elegant way, but hope that helps.

Comment: I am aware of that solution, but it is very inefficient. I am looking for an alternative to this.