# Trying to integrate a function this error shows: TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, physics

I am trying to do an integral over the first derivative of the Fermi-Dirac function f(E) and a transmission function t(E) to find a value for conductance, G. I am having a problem with the fact that t(E) is a summation and has multiple values that are vectorized.

This is the code that I have produced, the error shows up in the integral.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants as phys
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import math

E = np.expand_dims(np.linspace(0, 15, 10000), 1)
n = np.arange(0, 6)

h = 1/(1 + np.exp(-2*np.pi * (E-(n-0.5)*3)))

fermi = 2.5
kT = 0.2


def fermi_integral(E, fermi, T, n):
        return (np.exp((E-fermi)/(kT))/((np.exp((E-fermi)/(kT)) + 1)**2) * 1/(kT)) *  h
        
# above function is the integral part of G; df/dE * t(e)

result = integrate.quad(fermi_integral, 0, np.inf, args = (kT, fermi, E))

# integrating the function from 0 to infinity 

print('Result of integral;', result) 

G = (-(2*math.e**2)/phys.Planck) *np.array(result)

# multiplying the constants outside the integral in

print('Result for G:', G)
```

I am looking for multiple values but have not been able to produce any.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Error shows as following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\OneDrive\Documents\BSc_Project\Fermi.py:27 in <module>
    result = integrate.quad(fermi_integral, 0, np.inf, args = (kT, fermi, E))

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py:351 in quad
    retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\quadpack.py:465 in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagie(func,bound,infbounds,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you best, please provide the full traceback, knowing where the error is is as important as knowing what it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

scipy.quad does not support integration of vector valued functions. The vectorized version is: [scipy.quad_vec](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad_vec.html) and you need version 1.8.0 or newer for the "args" parameter.

Simply replacing quad with quad_vec works, but results in NaNs, although I think that might be a flaw in the logic, and not the code itself.

The answer was based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539106/vectorize-scipy-integrate-quad) SO question.